# Process InputStream blocks Console

Tags: java, process, console, console-application, inputstream

my Problem is, that a Process who I start over a ProcessBuilder blocks the Input in the Console that I want to read with a Scanner. Is there a possibility  to change that?

Here how I create the Process:

```
        String dir = "BungeeCord";
        String name = "BungeeCord.jar";

        if (bcprocesse == null) {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
            pb.directory(new File("MineCloud/" + dir));
            pb.command("java", "-Xms512M", "-Xmx2048M", "-jar", name);
            try {
               bcprocesse = pb.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println(AnsiColor.GREEN + dir + " wurde erfolgreich gestartet.");
        } else
            System.out.println(AnsiColor.RED + dir + " ist bereits gestartet.");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show how you set up the `Process`(`Builder`).

Comment: @AndyTurner Done.